# Thrust: Compiler error when switching from CUDA to OpenMP

Tags: openmp, thrust

I am learning some program which is compiled sucessfully for CUDA (v6.5). But when I switch to OpenMP I get the following errors:

> Error 9   error C2668: 'thrust::raw_reference_cast' : ambiguous call to overloaded function   C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include\thrust\detail\function.h    55  1
>
> Error 10  error C2780: 'enable_if_non_const_reference_or_tuple_of_iterator_references::type>::type thrust::detail::host_unary_transform_functor::operator ()(Tuple)' : expects 1 arguments - 0 provided C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include\thrust\detail\function.h    55  1
>
> Error 11  error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2013 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -IC:\Boost -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug-OMP(home) -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static     -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -DENABLE_LOGGING -DENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -DTHRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  /openmp" -o build\gopt-mpi\x64\Debug-OMP(home)\kernels_factory.cu.obj "C:\ALI\APOP\gopt-mpi\APOP_projects\src\cuda\kernels_factory.cu"" exited with code 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.5.targets 593 9

I work under Windows, Visual Studio 13 Community and switch to OpenMP according to https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Device-Backends. I made two changes in project properties, both for CUDA C/C++, Host:

1. "Additional compiler options" set as "/openmp"

2. "Preprocessor definitions" set as THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM=THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM_OMP

What should I do to correct the situation?

Comment: Some suggestions:  1. Update your CUDA to the latest version v7.5 (issues/bugs get fixed all the time).  2. If you can't do that, or there is still a problem with that,  update your thrust to the latest master.  3. Provide a short, complete code that will produce the errors you indicate.

Comment: @Robert, thanks - your second advice helped: I updated Thrust from 1.7.2 to 1.8.1 and errors escaped.